# the theme is unable to upload featured image in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, image-uploading

recently I changed a theme that originally it was able to upload featured images, but this changed theme of mine! is unable of doing that. 
I've tried replacing all the old files from old theme that I taught that I might have changed them, (one by one, and testing...) but I have no results. It's so frustrating please I put so much time on it, I just wanna know that I should focus on which files, I mean which files could have an effect on this problem???

I GET THIS ERROR ON UPLOADING: "An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later."

PS. I read this: [wordpress featured image uploader not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938252/wordpress-featured-image-uploader-not-working)
and it helped, but it's not an ultimate solution, I need this to be fixed.
REALLY Appreciate a HELP.

PSS. (I KNOW FOR A FACT THAT THIS IS JUST A THEME PROBLEM)

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old post but I was battling with this for some time and could not find a solution. I finally figured out my problem. For some reason after I updated the SIDEKICK plugin it started interfering with that function. As soon as I deleted SIDEKICK it worked. Not only that all the images I had tried to upload in my media center suddenly showed up. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

If it's a problem with uploading it either has something to do with your server or media settings? Did you change the location for media files. 
Or it has something to do with the rights on your server. Maybe the folder where you are trying to upload to doesn't have the proper read/write permissions?

Hope this helps

Comment: no these are not the problems, cause anything uploads pretty well but it doesn't show up in featured images window pop up in posts edit page. I can upload via media gallery etc. the problem here is about that featured image window, it maybe an ajax conflict or sth. I don't know where to look, I mean which file???

Comment: Ok,I clearly didn't understand your problem.How do you upload the image? Through the "Add featured image" button on the Edit Post page? I don't think it has anything to do with AJAX, because the page actually refreshes after upload. Are you sure your theme supports featured images?

Comment: Please use comments for *comments*. This will avoid you getting down-votes for answers that *are not answers* :)

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I'm quite a n00b at answering here. Always used to just get info. Thought it was about time I started contributing :)